# Get list of the day events from Google Calendar

Tags: google-calendar-api

I can not figure out how to get a list of events of a particular day, no matter whether they started the day or before and are not over yet?

In this page https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list I've read about two optional parameters **timeMax** — upper excl. bound of start event time and **timeMin** — lower incl. bound of end event time. 
But the question is, **How to set them in right way** to **get all events** that happens at **certain day**, e.g. 2012-10-25

If i'm right,
timeMax='2012-10-25T23:59:59Z' — gave me events that possibly starts from ? to this datetime
timeMin='2012-10-25T23:59:59Z' — gave me events that ends this datetime

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Actually, I think this should be:

```
timeMin='2012-10-25T00:00:00Z' 
timeMax='2012-10-26T00:00:00Z'
```

Since `timeMax` is exclusive in your example if you happen to have a calendar event on the 25th at 11:59:59pm you wouldn't retrieve it (rare, I know, but still possible).

This is how I've done it, even though now I'm running into another issue with retrieving calendar events.

Comment: If you use a DateTime instance, you should use: $timeMin->format(DateTime::ATOM);

Answer (score 1):

I beg your pardon, the setting of timeMin open-bound and that of timeMax is close-bound in the lookup period.
Setting the values to timeMin='2012-10-25T00:00:01Z' and timeMax='2012-10-25T23:59:59Z' will give the desired output.