# Get Calendar events between two dates

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client

How to get all events between two specific dates. For example i only want to get events between `1st of March 2013` & `28th of March 2013`.

I am using Google Calendar API v3. While in Google Calendar API v1 there was the facility for search between 2 dates using start-min & start-max. I am wondering what is the replacement for these two parameters in Google Calendar API v3?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Ok i got the answer. The new parameters in Google API V3 are `timeMin` & `timeMax` to filter events between 2 dates.

Comment: Glad you found the solution :)

Comment: Hi, your answer may be very helpfull for me. How did you apply these parameters ? Did you use it in Javascript ?

Comment: No i used it in Google PHP API.

Comment: Example for the PHP Client Libs:

`$service->events->listEvents('primary', array('timeMin'->'2013-03-01T00:00:00-04:00', 'timeMax'->'2013-03-28T23:59:59-04:00'));`

Note that the timestamps are in RFC 3339 format.

All of the parameters can be found here: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list

Comment: You can see how the values are formatted here as well - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13032011/get-list-of-the-day-events-from-google-calendar

Answer (score 0):

**Just add these two parameters to the query before getting the event feed:**

```
// Start date from where to get the events
$query->setStartMin('2013-01-01');
// End date
$query->setStartMax('2013-03-20');
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: i am using Google Calendar API v3. While in Google Calendar API v1 there was the facility for search between 2 dates using `start-min` & `start-max`. I am wondering what is the replacement for these two parameters in Google Calendar API v3.