# holiday api with respect to year

Tags: javascript

I am accessing Google Calendar API for holiday events in Pakistan. I want to get the holidays by selecting the year. But I am not able to find any solution in which i could send the year as a parameter in the API. The url that I am hitting to get the respective holidays is:

https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/en.pk%23holiday%40group.v.calendar.google.com/events?key=AIzaSyCj39smrGYzOMLMDPwu5VJtaWZqHD234UM

Please help me out to search the holidays according to the given year where i can add an extra parameter like:

"&year=2016"

and get the relevant year's result.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get Calendar events between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15516985/get-calendar-events-between-two-dates)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `timeMin` and `timeMax` `datetime` parameters to set the bounds of the query. With these parameters, you would only get the holidays from 2016:

```
timeMin: 2016-01-01T00:00:00Z
timeMax: 2017-01-01T00:00:00Z
```

Reference here: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list

Comment: I have tried this but it is not working. I added this to my URL but it is not showing me the desired result.

https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/en.pk%23holiday%40group.v.calendar.google.com/events?key=AIzaSyCj39smrGYzOMLMDPwu5VJtaWZqHD234UM&timeMin=2016-01-01T00:00:00Z&timeMax=2017-01-01T00:00:00Z

Comment: It seems that the calendar itself does not contain those dates. The `en.pk` starts from 2017, and e.g. `hu.hungarian` starts from 2014.