# Google busyFree endpoint, unexpected behaviour

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

I submit a POST request to the https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/freeBusy endpoint with the following data:

```
{
  "timeMin": "2017-02-23T08:00:00Z",
  "timeMax": "2017-02-23T09:00:00Z",
  "items": [
    {
      "id": "XXX@gmail.com"
    }
  ]
}
```

The calendar is containing an event at the specified date from 8:00AM to 9:00AM. The API returns the following:

```
{
    "kind": "calendar#freeBusy",
    "timeMin": "2017-02-23T08:00:00.000Z",
    "timeMax": "2017-02-23T09:00:00.000Z",
    "calendars": {
        "XXX@gmail.com": {
            "busy": []
        }
    }
}
```

That does not appear to be correct, as the specified timeMin and timeMax do exactly match the calendar item.

If I set the calendar item to 8:01AM - 9:00 or 8:00AM to 9:01 it returns the expected results (the calendar item). There is no detailed explanation on those time parameters, but it looks like that they have to be inbetween the actual calendar item?

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13032011/get-list-of-the-day-events-from-google-calendar/16196269#16196269), it's okay if you set to 8:01AM - 9:00 or 8:00AM to 9:01.

From the example in the above link, `timeMax` is set to `2012-10-25T23:59:59Z`. It was stated that *"Since timeMax is exclusive in your example if you happen to have a calendar event on the 25th at 11:59:59pm you wouldn't retrieve it (rare, I know, but still possible)."*

However, you can [file a report](https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/entry?template=Defect%20report) if you think this is a bug.

Hope this helps!